# Storage of large amount of global variables in MapReduce in java

Tags: java, mapreduce, global-variables

If we need to use more than one reducer to do reduce job where do our global variables are stored considering one reducer cannot have that much memory for global data of that job.

**Are they stored in HDFS and accessed by each reducer?**

Or

**We need to it explicitly.**

Answer (score 0):

**No.** They are not stored in HDFS. We need not to do anything explicitly.

Each of the `Reducer` run in a separate JVM and `Reducer` instance will have it's own variables maintained in the `jvm heap memory` area. So each of the Reducer will have its own instance of global or local variables. The object creation and storage is same as normal java program. There is nothing special happen with `Mapper` or `Reducer` objects.

Comment: What if reducer dont have that much amount of memory present?Say global array is of size 100Mb and our reducer have only 64Mb . Or in a more general aspect reducer has O(n) memory and global variable is of O(n^2).

Comment: @RuchiJaiswal what do you mean by that much memory is not present? Are you saying that global variable are storing the huge amount of data?

Comment: @RuchiJaiswal if the program is accessing the more memory than available as part part of the object state, then it will throw OutOfMemoryError and exit. The object state mean, variable which are part of reducer object state.

Comment: Yes, actually I am implementing a MRC class algorithm according to which a singel mapper/reducer has only O(n^(1-epsilon)) memory space and O(n^(1-epsilon)) reducers for a n-input algorithm. And I want to store O(n) array.

Comment: @RuchiJaiswal `O(n^(1-epsilon))` so code needs this much memory for string the temporary result while the reduce is running and that is giving you memory concern. Am I right. I would suggest you first give a try whether it fails or not, what error you get.

Comment: Well it is working fine with my current dataset but they are quite small.

Comment: @RuchiJaiswal could you provide some information about the state variable of the reducers? How they depend on the `n`.

Comment: Well it is a theoretical class which says what happens when we have limited  memory and limited number of reducers present. You can see defination given in 3.1  of this paper http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/soda10-mrc.pdf

Comment: @RuchiJaiswal If the state of the object is requiring more memory then available then program will fail with OutOfMemoryError. But if you concern is around, input to the reducer, which is key and list of values. The list of values is very large. Then reducer does not load all the value at once in the memory. It will fetch from the disk as it progress on the list iteration.

Comment: But it need to store intermediate data. It can do its job by splitting input into various parts but I want to find min value for each key and use it later in some other job.

Comment: @RuchiJaiswal for finding the minimum value for each key will require you only one instance variable (global). What is exactly you want to solve. Because you have started diverting from the original qiestion?

Comment: I am implementing MST. And I want to store data under o(n) bounds(not O(n)).